# Unable to push code on github due to unmerged files

Tags: git, github

I have been committing code on heroku directly using command below:

```
git push heroku master
```

But after enabling direct deploys from git master branch to heroku I have set my origin to git master using command below:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/example-web/example.git
```

Then after verifying whether branch has been set or not I used below command:

```
git remote -v
```

It has shown me output below:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/example.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/example.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/example-web/example.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/example-web/example.git (push)
```

Then after using below command to push code to master branch:

```
git push origin master
```

It is showing something like this:

```
To https://github.com/example-app/example.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/example-web/example.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then I have used git pull command:

```
git pull https://github.com/example-web/example.git
```

It is showing given results:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 275, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (275/275), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (219/219), done.
Receivring objeemote: Total 275 (delta 48), reused 274 (delta 47cts:  91% 
(251/275), 1), pack-reused 02.40 MiB | 1015.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects: 100% (275/275), 12.65 MiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (48/48), done.
From https://github.com/example-web/example
* branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging server.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in server.js
Auto-merging routes/register.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in routes/register.js
Auto-merging routes/postedBook.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in routes/postedBook.js
Auto-merging routes/loginBanners.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in routes/loginBanners.js
Auto-merging routes/loadBooks.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in routes/loadBooks.js
Auto-merging routes/deleteRow.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in routes/deleteRow.js
Auto-merging routes/banners.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in routes/banners.js
Auto-merging package.json
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in package.json
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Someone please let me know  how can I resolve conflicts and psh me code to master branch. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Git is telling you that the repo at `https://github.com/example-web/example.git` contains commits that you don't have locally. Is someone else contributing to that repo? Did you [rewrite your local history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)?

Comment: you need to edit all the conflicted files, fix the conflicts git add, git commit, and then push to master, though master is usually supposed to contain stable code, so instead of merging directly first checkout a different branch, resolve conflicts in that branch, test the code and then merge that branch to master and push the code...

Comment: The message `warning: no common commits` means that their repository and your repository are *not related to each other* (not clones). Modern Git will not attempt to merge such repositories, unless you force it to, because it rarely makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There’s two unmerged files here. According to the git checkout man-page, there’s a **--theirs** and **--ours** options on the command. **The former will keep the version of the file that you merged in**, **and the other will keep the original one we had.**

The following commands will keep the original file for server.js

```
git checkout --ours server.js
```

And the next command will let the file that is in the Git Remote Repository 
take over:

```
git checkout --theirs server.js
```

Sadly, these options are only in Git versions 1.6.1 and up. If you have an older version and don’t feel like upgrading, there’s ways to get around this. To emulate **--theirs**, we’d do:

```
git reset -- server.js
git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- server.js
```

And for **--ours**:

```
git reset -- server.js
git checkout ORIG_HEAD -- server.js
```

Of course, once you’ve got the conflicts worked out, **git add** whatever changes need
to be added in, and **git commit** away. If you’ve run into other problems with
merging that could possibly help out others, comment away!

Comment: There are *eight* conflicts listed. (Also, I don't know of anyone stuck with a version of Git predating 1.7.1, although that's possible.)